# Script to run showing next weeks appointsments

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like run a scheduled script to run Friday afternoons that will show next weeks appointments.

I have used this code in some of my other scripts, but cant figure it out for this situation.

```
AND Sched_Time >= TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1, 'IW') - 8 AND 
    Sched_Time <= TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1, 'IW') - 1
```

Comment: Add 8 days rather than subtracting.

Comment: I tried that and I didnt get any results. But when I run this: ` AND d.Sched_Time >= TO_DATE('2020-10-05 01:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS') 
 AND d.Sched_Time  < TO_DATE('2020-10-11 12:59:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')` it runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you try this code.

```
and Sched_Time >= TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW')+7
and Sched_Time < TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW')+14
```

TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW')+7 is '2020-10-05' and TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW')+14 is '2020-10-12' so it will include the datetime '2020-10-11 12:59:00' but not '2020-10-12'.

Comment: That was it, knew it was something simple.